# Two different GET routes linked to the same class - Flask/python

Tags: python, flask

My back end code looks like this:

```
@ns.route('/id/', methods=["DELETE", "GET"])
@ns.route('/', methods=["GET"])
class client(Resource):
       def get(self):
           return smthg
       def get(self, id):
           return smthg(id)
```

Will the code know which route it should access?  If not, can you recommend a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

When code does

```
def get(self):
    return smthg
def get(self, id):
    return smthg(id)
```

the second definition overrides the first. But also, neither route captures a url variable. Did you mean `/<id>/` ?

Comment: yes, I miswritten the route.  But I was wondering if it was possible to have two functions with different parameters